# Reason for particular pattern of clouds near sun

Tags: optics, everyday-life, atmospheric-science, density, optical-materials

[image][image]

In this picture it is clear that there is a larger no. Of clouds near the sun as compared to a distance farther. Moreover the clouds seem to form vortex rings around sun.

---

- why is there more density near the clouds , is it just an optical illusion.  If yes then what's the reason if no then why ?.

---

I'm not sure if this question suits this site so pls let me know if it doesnt

Comment: Are you sure that the cloud size is not a consequence of perspective and the ring formations are not a consequence of perception of light/shadow from a point source?

Comment: @Martin I feel there must be some reason associated not a perception of light

Comment: Sometimes the sky is blue except for one cloud blocking the sun. So what ?

Comment: @my2cts how does it relate to my qo.?

Comment: Have happening you observed this happening on different days and at different times of day?

Comment: @AdrianHoward I did see it many times but today kinda it was more clear it happened during sunset

Comment: There cannot be vortex rings around the sun for every observer. So either you were in a special place or this interpretation does not work. To me it looks more like the radial nature of the light and shadows accentuates certain cloud patterns.

Comment: @AndersSandberg special place means is there a specific place where such patterns can be observed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the cloud density is constant, it seems denser near the horizon, because there are more clouds for the same angle of vision.

The fact that the sun is near the horizon turns clouds brighter in that region, what calls our attention.